# Как правильно организовать базу данных SQLITE - очень много данных по дате

Tags: python, sqlite

Хочу сделать что-то вроде книги записи расходов.Каждый пользователь сможет записать сколько и на что он сегодня потратил.

Например:
Вчера:
еда - 500
топливо - 400
аптека - 150

Сегодня: Еда 300, развлечения - 700, одежда - 1500, топливо 500.

Потом это все суммируется за определенный период, и выдается отчет.
Еда - 800, топливо - 900 и т.д.

Как новичок, я вижу структуру только в одном виде:
Для каждого пользователя создается отдельная таблица, в которую уже идут записи, где вместо ID - дата.

Но это нормально, если будут пользоваться десяток человек, если сотни? Как правильно ее организовать?

Кроме, того, могут быть расходы, для которых нет колонки в БД, и она будет создаваться самостоятельно, например пользователь пишет "подарок маме 2000". И я создаю колонку podarok_mame, и записываю в него значение 2000 для этой даты.

Comment: Вы вот об этой книге на 52 страницы?
https://library.samdu.uz/download/24768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Для каждого пользователя создается отдельная таблица

Это абсолютно неправильно. Нужно использовать **две** таблицы:

1. Таблица пользователей (ID, ФИО)
2. Таблица расходов (ID, User_ID, DataAction, Pay)

И основная таблица (Расходы) ссылается на таблицу пользователей.

> я создаю колонку podarok_mame, и записываю в него значение

Это абсолютно неправильно. Надо расширить основную таблицу расходов так:

1. ID записи в этой таблице
2. User_ID - кто соврешил расход - ссылка на таблицу пользователей
3. DataAction - дата соврешения расхода
4. Pay - сумма платежа
5. **Type** - За что платим (Еда, топливо, мама...) **Ссылка** на таблицу типов платежей

Таким образом, получаем БД из трёх таблиц, в которой может быть неограниченное число пользователей и неограниченное число видов платежей.

Настоятельно рекомендую Вам прочить любую книжку по проектированию СУБД. Именно не про программирование, а про **проектирование**.

Например: В.В. Кирилов, "Основы проектирования реляционных БД"

Для начала, разберитесь, что такое первая, вторая и третья нормальные формы таблиц. Ну и про реляционную алгбру тоже надо иметь представление.